# java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.wicket.settings.def.JavaScriptLibrarySettings

Tags: java, wicket

I have wicket application and it sometimes fails on :

java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/wicket/settings/def/JavaScriptLibrarySettings
java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:1016)
java.base/java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:174)

I have this mvn configuration :

```
[INFO] com.dhl.crdb:crdb:war:1.2.2-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] +- com.dhl.webcommon:dhl-wc:jar:1.2.30.0:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework:spring-tx:jar:5.3.18:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.springframework:spring-beans:jar:5.3.18:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework:spring-webmvc:jar:5.3.18:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework:spring-core:jar:5.3.18:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.springframework:spring-jcl:jar:5.3.18:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework:spring-orm:jar:5.1.6.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.springframework:spring-jdbc:jar:5.1.6.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework:spring-web:jar:5.3.18:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework:spring-expression:jar:5.3.18:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework:spring-aop:jar:5.3.18:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework:spring-aspects:jar:5.3.18:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.aspectj:aspectjweaver:jar:1.9.7:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework:spring-jms:jar:5.3.18:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.springframework:spring-messaging:jar:5.3.18:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework:spring-context:jar:5.3.18:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework:spring-context-support:jar:5.3.18:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework.security:spring-security-core:jar:3.2.3.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- aopalliance:aopalliance:jar:1.0:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework.security:spring-security-web:jar:3.2.3.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework.security:spring-security-config:jar:3.2.3.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework.batch:spring-batch-core:jar:2.2.1.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.springframework.batch:spring-batch-infrastructure:jar:2.2.1.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  \- org.springframework.retry:spring-retry:jar:1.0.2.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- com.thoughtworks.xstream:xstream:jar:1.3:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  \- xpp3:xpp3_min:jar:1.1.4c:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.codehaus.jettison:jettison:jar:1.1:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework.ldap:spring-ldap-core:jar:1.3.2.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.apache.wicket:wicket-core:jar:8.14.0:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- com.github.openjson:openjson:jar:1.0.11:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.apache.wicket:wicket-request:jar:8.14.0:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.apache.wicket:wicket-util:jar:8.14.0:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.danekja:jdk-serializable-functional:jar:1.8.6:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.apache.wicket:wicket-spring:jar:8.14.0:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.apache.wicket:wicket-ioc:jar:8.14.0:compile
[INFO] |  |     +- cglib:cglib-nodep:jar:3.2.12:compile
[INFO] |  |     +- javax.inject:javax.inject:jar:1:compile
[INFO] |  |     \- org.ow2.asm:asm-util:jar:7.1:compile
[INFO] |  |        +- org.ow2.asm:asm:jar:7.1:compile
[INFO] |  |        +- org.ow2.asm:asm-tree:jar:7.1:compile
[INFO] |  |        \- org.ow2.asm:asm-analysis:jar:7.1:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.wicketstuff:wicketstuff-minis:jar:8.14.0:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.apache.wicket:wicket-bean-validation:jar:8.13.0:compile
[INFO] |  +- com.vaynberg.wicket.select2:wicket-select2:jar:4.1:compile
[INFO] |  +- cas:casclient:jar:2.1.1:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- commons-logging:commons-logging:jar:1.0.4:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.jasig.cas:cas-client-core:jar:3.1.2:compile
[INFO] |  +- joda-time:joda-time-hibernate:jar:1.3:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.jadira.usertype:usertype.jodatime:jar:2.0.1:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.jadira.usertype:usertype.spi:jar:2.0.1:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.hibernate:hibernate-core:jar:5.3.6.Final:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- javax.persistence:javax.persistence-api:jar:2.2:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.javassist:javassist:jar:3.23.1-GA:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- net.bytebuddy:byte-buddy:jar:1.8.17:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- antlr:antlr:jar:2.7.7:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.jboss.spec.javax.transaction:jboss-transaction-api_1.2_spec:jar:1.1.1.Final:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.jboss:jandex:jar:2.0.5.Final:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- javax.activation:javax.activation-api:jar:1.2.0:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- dom4j:dom4j:jar:1.6.1:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.hibernate.common:hibernate-commons-annotations:jar:5.0.4.Final:compile
[INFO] |  +- commons-dbcp:commons-dbcp:jar:1.4:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- commons-pool:commons-pool:jar:1.5.4:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.hibernate:hibernate-ehcache:jar:5.3.6.Final:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- net.sf.ehcache:ehcache:jar:2.10.3:compile
[INFO] |  +- com.ibm.icu:icu4j:jar:4.0.1:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.apache.xmlbeans:xmlbeans:jar:2.6.0:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- stax:stax-api:jar:1.0.1:compile
[INFO] |  +- com.oracle:ojdbc16:jar:11.2.0.3.0:runtime
[INFO] |  +- commons-lang:commons-lang:jar:2.6:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.aspectj:aspectjrt:jar:1.5.4:compile
[INFO] |  +- log4j:log4j:jar:1.2.17:compile
[INFO] |  +- commons-io:commons-io:jar:2.4:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.hibernate:hibernate-envers:jar:5.3.6.Final:compile
[INFO] |  +- javax.mail:mail:jar:1.4.4:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- javax.activation:activation:jar:1.1:compile
[INFO] |  +- com.code-troopers:wicket-editable-grid:jar:0.1:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.apache.cxf:cxf-rt-databinding-jaxb:jar:2.7.3:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.apache.cxf:cxf-api:jar:2.7.3:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  +- org.codehaus.woodstox:woodstox-core-asl:jar:4.1.4:runtime
[INFO] |  |  |  |  \- org.codehaus.woodstox:stax2-api:jar:3.1.1:runtime
[INFO] |  |  |  +- org.apache.ws.xmlschema:xmlschema-core:jar:2.0.3:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  \- wsdl4j:wsdl4j:jar:1.6.2:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.apache.cxf:cxf-rt-core:jar:2.7.3:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- com.sun.xml.bind:jaxb-impl:jar:2.1.13:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- com.sun.xml.bind:jaxb-xjc:jar:2.1.13:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.apache.cxf:cxf-rt-frontend-jaxws:jar:2.7.3:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- xml-resolver:xml-resolver:jar:1.2:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- asm:asm:jar:3.3.1:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.apache.cxf:cxf-rt-bindings-soap:jar:2.7.3:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.apache.cxf:cxf-rt-bindings-xml:jar:2.7.3:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.apache.cxf:cxf-rt-frontend-simple:jar:2.7.3:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.apache.cxf:cxf-rt-ws-addr:jar:2.7.3:compile
[INFO] |  |     \- org.apache.cxf:cxf-rt-ws-policy:jar:2.7.3:compile
[INFO] |  |        \- org.apache.neethi:neethi:jar:3.0.2:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.apache.cxf:cxf-rt-transports-http:jar:2.7.3:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.apache.httpcomponents:httpclient:jar:4.4:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.apache.httpcomponents:httpcore:jar:4.4:compile
[INFO] |  +- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-core:jar:2.9.1:compile
[INFO] |  +- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-annotations:jar:2.9.1:compile
[INFO] |  +- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-databind:jar:2.9.1:compile
[INFO] |  +- com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype:jackson-datatype-joda:jar:2.9.1:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- joda-time:joda-time:jar:2.7:compile
[INFO] |  +- com.googlecode.wicket-jquery-ui:wicket-jquery-ui:jar:8.13.0:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- com.googlecode.wicket-jquery-ui:wicket-jquery-ui-core:jar:8.13.0:compile
[INFO] |  +- com.dhl.webcommon:saml-filter:jar:1.0.10.0:compile
[INFO] |  +- com.dhl.webcommon:dhl-dbc:jar:1.1.82.0:compile
[INFO] |  +- com.dhl.webcommon:dhl-resources:jar:1.1.160.0:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.flywaydb:flyway-core:jar:4.0.3:compile
[INFO] +- org.codehaus.mojo:animal-sniffer-annotations:jar:1.14:compile
[INFO] +- javax.validation:validation-api:jar:2.0.1.Final:compile
[INFO] +- ch.qos.logback:logback-core:jar:1.2.3:compile
[INFO] +- ch.qos.logback:logback-classic:jar:1.2.3:compile
[INFO] +- org.slf4j:slf4j-api:jar:1.7.25:compile
[INFO] +- javax.xml.ws:jaxws-api:jar:2.2.12:compile
[INFO] |  \- javax.xml.soap:javax.xml.soap-api:jar:1.3.5:compile
[INFO] +- javax.jws:javax.jws-api:jar:1.1:compile
[INFO] +- net.logstash.logback:logstash-logback-encoder:jar:6.3:compile
[INFO] +- org.codehaus.janino:janino:jar:3.0.6:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.codehaus.janino:commons-compiler:jar:3.0.6:compile
[INFO] +- javax.annotation:javax.annotation-api:jar:1.3.2:compile
[INFO] +- org.springframework.security.oauth:spring-security-oauth2:jar:2.0.12.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  +- commons-codec:commons-codec:jar:1.9:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.codehaus.jackson:jackson-mapper-asl:jar:1.9.13:compile
[INFO] |     \- org.codehaus.jackson:jackson-core-asl:jar:1.9.13:compile
[INFO] +- net.ttddyy:datasource-proxy:jar:1.4.1:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.mockito:mockito-core:jar:1.9.5:compile
[INFO] |     \- org.objenesis:objenesis:jar:1.0:compile
[INFO] +- junit:junit:jar:4.11:test
[INFO] |  \- org.hamcrest:hamcrest-core:jar:1.3:test
[INFO] +- org.hsqldb:hsqldb:jar:2.2.8:test
[INFO] +- org.mockito:mockito-all:jar:1.9.5:test
[INFO] +- javax.servlet:javax.servlet-api:jar:3.0.1:test
[INFO] +- com.jayway.jsonpath:json-path:jar:0.8.1:test
[INFO] |  \- net.minidev:json-smart:jar:1.1.1:test
[INFO] +- com.jayway.jsonpath:json-path-assert:jar:0.8.1:test
[INFO] |  \- org.hamcrest:hamcrest-library:jar:1.2.1:test
[INFO] +- org.wicketstuff:wicketstuff-tinymce:jar:6.30.0:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.apache.wicket:wicket-extensions:jar:6.30.0:compile
[INFO] |  +- commons-collections:commons-collections:jar:3.2.1:compile
[INFO] |  +- net.sf.jazzy:jazzy:jar:0.5.2-rtext-1.4.1:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.json:json:jar:20090211:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.apache.wicket:wicket:pom:6.30.0:compile
[INFO] +- javax.servlet:servlet-api:jar:2.5:provided
[INFO] +- org.apache.tika:tika-core:jar:1.17:compile
[INFO] +- org.hibernate.validator:hibernate-validator:jar:6.0.12.Final:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.jboss.logging:jboss-logging:jar:3.3.2.Final:compile
[INFO] |  \- com.fasterxml:classmate:jar:1.3.4:compile
[INFO] +- org.hibernate.validator:hibernate-validator-annotation-processor:jar:6.0.12.Final:compile
[INFO] +- org.hibernate.javax.persistence:hibernate-jpa-2.1-api:jar:1.0.2.Final:compile
[INFO] +- org.apache.poi:poi:jar:3.17:compile
[INFO] +- org.apache.poi:poi-ooxml:jar:3.17:compile
[INFO] |  \- com.github.virtuald:curvesapi:jar:1.04:compile
[INFO] +- org.apache.poi:ooxml-schemas:jar:1.1:compile
[INFO] +- org.apache.poi:poi-ooxml-schemas:jar:3.14:compile
[INFO] +- javax.xml.bind:jaxb-api:jar:2.2.11:compile
[INFO] +- io.springfox:springfox-swagger2:jar:2.9.2:compile
[INFO] |  +- io.swagger:swagger-annotations:jar:1.5.20:compile
[INFO] |  +- io.swagger:swagger-models:jar:1.5.20:compile
[INFO] |  +- io.springfox:springfox-spi:jar:2.9.2:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- io.springfox:springfox-core:jar:2.9.2:compile
[INFO] |  +- io.springfox:springfox-schema:jar:2.9.2:compile
[INFO] |  +- io.springfox:springfox-swagger-common:jar:2.9.2:compile
[INFO] |  +- io.springfox:springfox-spring-web:jar:2.9.2:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework.plugin:spring-plugin-core:jar:1.2.0.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework.plugin:spring-plugin-metadata:jar:1.2.0.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.mapstruct:mapstruct:jar:1.2.0.Final:compile
[INFO] +- io.springfox:springfox-swagger-ui:jar:2.9.2:compile
[INFO] +- com.google.guava:guava:jar:21.0:compile
[INFO] +- io.jsonwebtoken:jjwt:jar:0.7.0:compile
[INFO] +- com.google.code.findbugs:jsr305:jar:3.0.2:compile
[INFO] +- org.apache.commons:commons-collections4:jar:4.1:compile
[INFO] +- io.swagger:swagger-jaxrs:jar:1.6.0:compile
[INFO] |  +- io.swagger:swagger-core:jar:1.6.0:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.apache.commons:commons-lang3:jar:3.2.1:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat:jackson-dataformat-yaml:jar:2.10.1:compile
[INFO] |  |     \- org.yaml:snakeyaml:jar:1.24:compile
[INFO] |  +- javax.ws.rs:jsr311-api:jar:1.1.1:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.reflections:reflections:jar:0.9.11:compile
[INFO] +- org.owasp.esapi:esapi:jar:2.2.3.1:compile
[INFO] |  +- com.io7m.xom:xom:jar:1.2.10:compile
[INFO] |  +- commons-beanutils:commons-beanutils:jar:1.9.4:compile
[INFO] |  +- commons-configuration:commons-configuration:jar:1.10:compile
[INFO] |  +- commons-fileupload:commons-fileupload:jar:1.3.3:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.apache-extras.beanshell:bsh:jar:2.0b6:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.owasp.antisamy:antisamy:jar:1.6.3:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- net.sourceforge.nekohtml:nekohtml:jar:1.9.22:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.apache.xmlgraphics:batik-css:jar:1.14:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  +- org.apache.xmlgraphics:batik-shared-resources:jar:1.14:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  +- org.apache.xmlgraphics:batik-util:jar:1.14:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  |  +- org.apache.xmlgraphics:batik-constants:jar:1.14:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  |  \- org.apache.xmlgraphics:batik-i18n:jar:1.14:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  \- org.apache.xmlgraphics:xmlgraphics-commons:jar:2.6:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- xerces:xercesImpl:jar:2.12.1:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- xml-apis:xml-apis-ext:jar:1.3.04:compile
[INFO] |  \- xml-apis:xml-apis:jar:1.4.01:compile
[INFO] \- org.springframework:spring-test:jar:4.3.1.RELEASE:test
```

Can someone please give me a point how to solve this issue? Im little stuck with it. In org.apache.wicket.settings there is JavaScriptLibrarySettings in wicket core. I dont know how to solve this issue, maybe there is some obsolate dependency. Thanks for help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Almost all Wicket dependencies are 8.14.0 but few are 8.13.0 (not really a problem but better keep them in sync):

- org.apache.wicket:wicket-bean-validation:jar:8.13.0:compile
- com.googlecode.wicket-jquery-ui:wicket-jquery-ui:jar:8.13.0:compile
- com.googlecode.wicket-jquery-ui:wicket-jquery-ui-core:jar:8.13.0:compile

The real problem is:

```
[INFO] +- org.wicketstuff:wicketstuff-tinymce:jar:6.30.0:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.apache.wicket:wicket-extensions:jar:6.30.0:compile
[INFO] |  +- commons-collections:commons-collections:jar:3.2.1:compile
[INFO] |  +- net.sf.jazzy:jazzy:jar:0.5.2-rtext-1.4.1:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.json:json:jar:20090211:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.apache.wicket:wicket:pom:6.30.0:compile
```

Do not mix Wicket deps with differences in the major version (8 vs 6)!