# Compile error on connot access org.apache.wicket.extensions.markup.html.repeater.data.grid.ICellPopulator

Tags: java, maven, wicket

I have problem with my maven build. It throws error

```
[ERROR] \Users\pkostrou\IdeaProjects\dhl-wc-1.2.30.0\src\main\java\com\dhl\web\component\table\CheckboxPropertyColumn.java:[8,66] error: cannot access ICellPopulat
or
```

But `org.apache.wicket.extensions.markup.html.repeater.data.grid.ICellPopulator` I have in my classpath on

```
   <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.wicket</groupId>
        <artifactId>wicket-extensions</artifactId>
        <version>9.0.0</version>
    </dependency>
```

When I try to doubleclick ICellPopulator in Idea, It normally open class in dependency library.

Can someone give me a point how to solve this issue

My mvn dependency:tree

```
[INFO] com.dhl.webcommon:dhl-wc:jar:1.2.30.0
[INFO] +- org.springframework:spring-tx:jar:5.3.18:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.springframework:spring-beans:jar:5.3.18:compile
[INFO] +- org.springframework:spring-webmvc:jar:5.3.18:compile
[INFO] +- org.springframework:spring-core:jar:5.3.18:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.springframework:spring-jcl:jar:5.3.18:compile
[INFO] +- org.springframework:spring-orm:jar:5.1.6.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.springframework:spring-jdbc:jar:5.1.6.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] +- org.springframework:spring-web:jar:5.3.18:compile
[INFO] +- org.springframework:spring-expression:jar:5.3.18:compile
[INFO] +- org.springframework:spring-aop:jar:5.3.18:compile
[INFO] +- org.springframework:spring-aspects:jar:5.3.18:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.aspectj:aspectjweaver:jar:1.9.7:compile
[INFO] +- org.springframework:spring-test:jar:5.3.18:compile
[INFO] +- org.springframework:spring-jms:jar:5.3.18:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.springframework:spring-messaging:jar:5.3.18:compile
[INFO] +- org.springframework:spring-context:jar:5.3.18:compile
[INFO] +- org.springframework:spring-context-support:jar:5.3.18:compile
[INFO] +- org.springframework.security:spring-security-core:jar:3.2.3.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  \- aopalliance:aopalliance:jar:1.0:compile
[INFO] +- org.springframework.security:spring-security-web:jar:3.2.3.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] +- org.springframework.security:spring-security-config:jar:3.2.3.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] +- org.springframework.batch:spring-batch-core:jar:2.2.1.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework.batch:spring-batch-infrastructure:jar:2.2.1.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.springframework.retry:spring-retry:jar:1.0.2.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  +- com.thoughtworks.xstream:xstream:jar:1.3:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- xpp3:xpp3_min:jar:1.1.4c:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.codehaus.jettison:jettison:jar:1.1:compile
[INFO] +- org.springframework.ldap:spring-ldap-core:jar:1.3.2.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] +- org.apache.wicket:wicket-core:jar:9.8.0:compile
[INFO] |  +- com.github.openjson:openjson:jar:1.0.12:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.apache.wicket:wicket-request:jar:9.8.0:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.apache.wicket:wicket-util:jar:9.8.0:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- commons-fileupload:commons-fileupload:jar:1.4:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.apache.commons:commons-collections4:jar:4.4:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.danekja:jdk-serializable-functional:jar:1.9.0:compile
[INFO] +- org.apache.wicket:wicket-spring:jar:9.8.0:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.apache.wicket:wicket-ioc:jar:9.8.0:compile
[INFO] |     +- cglib:cglib:jar:3.3.0:compile
[INFO] |     +- javax.inject:javax.inject:jar:1:compile
[INFO] |     \- org.ow2.asm:asm:jar:9.1:compile
[INFO] +- org.wicketstuff:wicketstuff-minis:jar:9.8.0:compile
[INFO] +- org.apache.wicket:wicket-bean-validation:jar:9.8.0:compile
[INFO] +- com.vaynberg.wicket.select2:wicket-select2:jar:4.1:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.json:json:jar:20170516:compile
[INFO] +- cas:casclient:jar:2.1.1:compile
[INFO] |  +- javax.servlet:servlet-api:jar:2.3:compile
[INFO] |  \- commons-logging:commons-logging:jar:1.0.4:compile
[INFO] +- org.jasig.cas:cas-client-core:jar:3.1.2:compile
[INFO] +- joda-time:joda-time-hibernate:jar:1.3:compile
[INFO] +- org.jadira.usertype:usertype.jodatime:jar:2.0.1:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.jadira.usertype:usertype.spi:jar:2.0.1:compile
[INFO] +- com.google.guava:guava:jar:11.0.2:compile
[INFO] |  \- com.google.code.findbugs:jsr305:jar:1.3.9:compile
[INFO] +- org.hibernate:hibernate-core:jar:5.3.6.Final:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.jboss.logging:jboss-logging:jar:3.3.2.Final:compile
[INFO] |  +- javax.persistence:javax.persistence-api:jar:2.2:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.javassist:javassist:jar:3.23.1-GA:compile
[INFO] |  +- net.bytebuddy:byte-buddy:jar:1.8.17:compile
[INFO] |  +- antlr:antlr:jar:2.7.7:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.jboss.spec.javax.transaction:jboss-transaction-api_1.2_spec:jar:1.1.1.Final:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.jboss:jandex:jar:2.0.5.Final:compile
[INFO] |  +- com.fasterxml:classmate:jar:1.3.4:compile
[INFO] |  +- javax.activation:javax.activation-api:jar:1.2.0:compile
[INFO] |  +- dom4j:dom4j:jar:1.6.1:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.hibernate.common:hibernate-commons-annotations:jar:5.0.4.Final:compile
[INFO] +- commons-dbcp:commons-dbcp:jar:1.4:compile
[INFO] |  \- commons-pool:commons-pool:jar:1.5.4:compile
[INFO] +- javax.validation:validation-api:jar:1.0.0.GA:compile
[INFO] +- org.hibernate:hibernate-validator-annotation-processor:jar:4.2.0.Final:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.hibernate:hibernate-validator:jar:4.2.0.Final:compile
[INFO] +- org.hibernate:hibernate-ehcache:jar:5.3.6.Final:compile
[INFO] |  \- net.sf.ehcache:ehcache:jar:2.10.3:compile
[INFO] +- com.ibm.icu:icu4j:jar:4.0.1:compile
[INFO] +- org.apache.poi:poi:jar:3.13:compile
[INFO] |  \- commons-codec:commons-codec:jar:1.9:compile
[INFO] +- org.apache.poi:poi-ooxml:jar:3.13:compile
[INFO] +- org.apache.poi:poi-ooxml-schemas:jar:3.13:compile
[INFO] +- org.apache.xmlbeans:xmlbeans:jar:2.6.0:compile
[INFO] |  \- stax:stax-api:jar:1.0.1:compile
[INFO] +- com.oracle:ojdbc16:jar:11.2.0.3.0:runtime
[INFO] +- commons-lang:commons-lang:jar:2.6:compile
[INFO] +- org.aspectj:aspectjrt:jar:1.5.4:compile
[INFO] +- log4j:log4j:jar:1.2.17:compile
[INFO] +- org.slf4j:slf4j-api:jar:1.7.2:compile
[INFO] +- org.slf4j:slf4j-log4j12:jar:1.7.2:compile
[INFO] +- commons-io:commons-io:jar:2.4:compile
[INFO] +- junit:junit:jar:4.10:test
[INFO] |  \- org.hamcrest:hamcrest-core:jar:1.1:test
[INFO] +- org.hibernate:hibernate-envers:jar:5.3.6.Final:compile
[INFO] +- javax.mail:mail:jar:1.4.4:compile
[INFO] |  \- javax.activation:activation:jar:1.1:compile
[INFO] +- com.code-troopers:wicket-editable-grid:jar:0.1:compile
[INFO] +- org.apache.wicket:wicket-extensions:jar:9.8.0:compile
[INFO] +- org.apache.cxf:cxf-rt-databinding-jaxb:jar:2.7.3:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.apache.cxf:cxf-api:jar:2.7.3:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.codehaus.woodstox:woodstox-core-asl:jar:4.1.4:runtime
[INFO] |  |  |  \- org.codehaus.woodstox:stax2-api:jar:3.1.1:runtime
[INFO] |  |  +- org.apache.ws.xmlschema:xmlschema-core:jar:2.0.3:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- wsdl4j:wsdl4j:jar:1.6.2:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.apache.cxf:cxf-rt-core:jar:2.7.3:compile
[INFO] |  +- com.sun.xml.bind:jaxb-impl:jar:2.1.13:compile
[INFO] |  \- com.sun.xml.bind:jaxb-xjc:jar:2.1.13:compile
[INFO] +- org.apache.cxf:cxf-rt-frontend-jaxws:jar:2.7.3:compile
[INFO] |  +- xml-resolver:xml-resolver:jar:1.2:compile
[INFO] |  +- asm:asm:jar:3.3.1:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.apache.cxf:cxf-rt-bindings-soap:jar:2.7.3:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.apache.cxf:cxf-rt-bindings-xml:jar:2.7.3:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.apache.cxf:cxf-rt-frontend-simple:jar:2.7.3:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.apache.cxf:cxf-rt-ws-addr:jar:2.7.3:compile
[INFO] |     \- org.apache.cxf:cxf-rt-ws-policy:jar:2.7.3:compile
[INFO] |        \- org.apache.neethi:neethi:jar:3.0.2:compile
[INFO] +- org.apache.cxf:cxf-rt-transports-http:jar:2.7.3:compile
[INFO] +- org.apache.httpcomponents:httpclient:jar:4.4:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.apache.httpcomponents:httpcore:jar:4.4:compile
[INFO] +- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-core:jar:2.9.1:compile
[INFO] +- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-annotations:jar:2.9.1:compile
[INFO] +- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-databind:jar:2.9.1:compile
[INFO] +- com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype:jackson-datatype-joda:jar:2.9.1:compile
[INFO] |  \- joda-time:joda-time:jar:2.7:compile
[INFO] +- com.googlecode.wicket-jquery-ui:wicket-jquery-ui:jar:9.8.0:compile
[INFO] |  \- com.googlecode.wicket-jquery-ui:wicket-jquery-ui-core:jar:9.8.0:compile
[INFO] +- com.dhl.webcommon:saml-filter:jar:1.0.10.0:compile
[INFO] +- com.dhl.webcommon:dhl-dbc:jar:1.1.82.0:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.hibernate.javax.persistence:hibernate-jpa-2.1-api:jar:1.0.0.Final:compile
[INFO] |  \- commons-beanutils:commons-beanutils:jar:1.9.2:compile
[INFO] |     \- commons-collections:commons-collections:jar:3.2.1:compile
[INFO] +- com.dhl.webcommon:dhl-resources:jar:1.1.160.0:compile
[INFO] \- org.flywaydb:flyway-core:jar:4.0.3:compile
```

Hope it will help to solve my issue. It seems that all dependency is there, but maven still cant resolve class GenericPanel

Comment: I am pretty sure it is related to https://stackoverflow.com/a/71876080/497381. There you used Wicket 8.13, 8.14 and 6.30 in the classpath. Now I see you use 9.0.0 too. Why 9.0.0 ?! If you update your app then use the latest 9.8.0

Comment: Still there is problem with ICellPopulator. I try to delete wicket from my maven repo and import them again, but still there is same error. And also update to latest 9.8.0 still doesnt work.

Comment: When I try to update Wicket to 9.8.0, there is problem with class org.apache.wicket.markup.html.panel.GenericPanel;

Comment: I also try do delete my mvn local repository, but with same problem.

Comment: Please share the output of `mvn dependency:tree`

Comment: I add it into my question.

Answer (score 0):

The classpath looks OK!

I guess the downloaded wicket-extensions.jar got corrupted somehow. Delete it from ~/.m2/repository/org/apache/wicket/wicket-extensions/9.8.0 and try again. Maven will re-download it from Maven Central.